# Defining the offset of polar axis plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a polar axis plot that looks like this:

[image]

I want 190 degrees to be at the top part of the plot, instead of 180, what can I do to change the plot?

In my script, the relevant segment reads:

```
ax.set_theta_zero_location("S")
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
```

This allows me to get a plot facing south, and also having the ticks (degrees) set out in the opposite direction. I now want to slightly refine my plot, by turning the plot a little bit, so that 190 degrees is the top part of the plot. How can I do that?

I've tried to add this line:

```
ax.set_theta_offset(-np.pi/18)
```

and when that did not work, I tried to add:

```
ax.set_theta_offset(-10)
```

But either of these two lines seem to shift the plot a lot, rather than the 10 degrees I am trying to get. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get 190° on top of the plot, you need to rotate it by -80°.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_theta_offset(np.deg2rad(-80))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or, if you want to change the ticks as well,

```
ax.set_xticks(np.deg2rad(np.arange(0,360,45)+10))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Would it also be possible to get those marker lines to shift, such that the topmost line is connected to 190 and not 180 degrees, and 190 degrees to be printed rather than 180?